# How to refresh/reload CMSCockpit's current element by a button?

Tags: content-management-system, sap-commerce-cloud, page-refresh

Let's say my task is to create a button in CMSCockpit, which has to be displayed on every XY type object. My button has some logic in it, for eg. the user is able to upload some child objects under the current XY object, but after the upload the button's task is to refresh/reload the current object, so the user is able to see the uploaded child elements.

How could I implement the second task (refreshing/reloading the current object)?

Cheers,
Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

​We have managed to solve this issue by calling the **UISessionUtils.getCurrentSession().getCurrentPerspective().getEditorArea().setCurrentObject(this.typedObject);** from the newly created renderer class.